# New drive on PC for no reason

Tags: windows-7, drivers

So recently I fell for a tech support scam. I reset my computer to a couple days before and ran a bunch of virus scans and everything looked good. But today I turned on my PC and theres a drive called ESP(D:), and in the drive theres 4 files.
The first file is a folder called EFI. In EFI theres 2 folders called Boot and Microsoft. Theres a bunch of files in both of those.
The second file is en-us. In en-us theres a file called bootmgr.efi.mui.
The third file is called BOOTMGR and its a system file.
The fourth file is MASTER.LOG and its a text file.
I just want to make sure this isn't anything from the scammers. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What was the *"tech support scam"* you fell for anyway? What exactly happened?

Comment: +1 for admitting you fell for a tech support Scam.

Answer (score 3):

That is the [EFI System Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) that holds important data about the start-up configuration of your PC. Deleting any of those file or formatting will result in a non-bootable PC!

That partition should not be visible in Windows Explorer. ESP does not need a drive letter, so you can unassign it from Disk Management. And again, be sure you are not deleting or formatting it!