# How to disable automounting under Windows 10? (Windows is messing up my Ubuntu partitions)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot

I have recently run some updates on my Windows 10, which is installed on a dual boot with Kubuntu 16.10. Since the update, Windows is auto mounting not only the Windows partition `C:`, but also the EFI and Ubuntu partitions.

Since that, I am not able to boot Kubuntu until I plug in a GParted live usb an run the `Check and repair` process on my Ubuntu partition. After that I am able to boot into Kubuntu.

Apparently when running Windows, it messes up my non-windows partitions: In the Disk Properties window I can see that two events happened: `Device configured (disk.inf)` and `Device started (disk)`.

**Is there a way to disable configuring the EFI and Ubuntu partitions under Windows 10?**

I have found a following tutorial, which advises me to remove the drive path using the Disk Management utility (http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-hide-or-dismount-partition-windows), but I have the "Change Drive Letter and Paths" option greyed out, so I am not able to do it this way.

**Edit:** Thank you to linking the possible duplicate: [Did Windows 10 just add a partition to my hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/1112651/did-windows-10-just-add-a-partition-to-my-hard-drive)
I have tried the proposed `diskpart` solution, but the `select` command was not able to find the partitions (but in the file explorer they had letters assigned).

Comment: Go into Disk Mangement and unassign the drive letter for both partitions.  The EFI partition should never be assigned a drive letter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did Windows 10 just add a partition to my hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/1112651/did-windows-10-just-add-a-partition-to-my-hard-drive)

Comment: Additional Duplicate: [New drive on PC for no reason](http://superuser.com/questions/881595/new-drive-on-pc-for-no-reason/881599#881599)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was a dumb mistake, I should have thought of it sooner.

Back in the day, when I installed Windows 10 on this computer, I also installed **ext2fsd** (https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/), to be able to access my Ubuntu partition from Windows. Before the upgrade it worked (I was able to manually mount and unmount the partition using this tool) and I was able to boot to Ubuntu without having to fix the partition.

After the update something probable went wrong with the ext2fsd configuration and it started messing up my partition system.

The solution was to uninstall the ext2fsd tool from Windows.